# Spider Man's wall climbing machine

Tags: visual

[image: The Climber]

When Spider Man invented his wall-climbing machine, everyone
thought it wouldn't work. They were right! Quite simply, there was nothing
to hold the machine onto the wall. But how much of a screwbrain was
Spidey? Did he at least manage to get the wheels that were in contact with
the wall (A and B) to turn the right way? The inside of the machine is shown
above with pulleys (black) and cogs (white).

Which way do wheels A and B rotate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> They both rotate **anti clockwise**!

Diagram below for methodology.

> [image]

It may also be worth noting...

> That considering its a wall Climbing machine, **anticlockwise** is the **correct** direction for both wheels, to make him go **UP** the wall. If only he had got his wheels to stick.

Comment: Great, Well stated :)